# adding string Dynamic java script in asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, runtime

I'm trying to write java script at runtime in which i have to find the radiobuttonlist at runtime but i have to pass it name in string datatype

```
 Dim scriptText As String = ""
        scriptText &= "function DisplayCharCount(){

        scriptText &= " console.log(document.getElementById(**RadioButtonList1**));"

        scriptText &= "}"
        ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me.GetType(), _
            "CounterScript", scriptText, True)
```

**RadioButtonList1** should be enter in from string like **"RadioButtonList1"** so how i
m suppose to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use double "" or '

```
        Dim scriptText As String = ""
        scriptText &= "function DisplayCharCount(){"

        scriptText &= " console.log(document.getElementById('RadioButtonList1'));"

        scriptText &= "}"
        ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me.GetType(), _
            "CounterScript", scriptText, True)
```